# in what format to save text notes to a database with nodejs mysql to display it later?

Tags: html, mysql, node.js

I have a register and login website such that if a user logs in, he has a text area to write a note, and I would like to save his notes in a database with node js, to later display the notes of each user if he requests it

Comment: As...text? Are you asking which format to consider, as in, "markdown, RTF, HTML"? or are you asking which column type to store them in in MySQL as in "TEXT or VARCHAR or ..."?

Comment: i ask for column type of course, that allow me to display them later if the user log in and consult his notes to modify them for exemple

Comment: Well, [what types does MySQL have for text](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-strings)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. With respect, you haven't told us enough for us to help you. How long can your text notes be? Does each user have just one note, or can they enter multiple notes? Will you need to search your notes looking for words or phrases in them? Please [edit] your question, or ask another, to provide more details.